# Show Opportunity Stage Name Picklist read only based on user role

Tags: salesforce

I am new to Salesforce and need an idea how is possible that suppose I have one user named "ABC".
I don't want to show the Opportunity `StageName` picklist when "ABC" user login in editable form or just want to show the `StageName` value in textfield or anything other.

I tried to set the permission under setup but not achieved what I want. I just came to know that formula field or formula will used for that, as I am new to Salesforce so I unable to create a formula field.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this You should try field level security settings:
https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/admin_fls.htm

You can select per field /profile combination which fields are visible and which are editable.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot apply FLS on system required fields neither can you make them read only on the page layouts. You also cannot remove such fields from page layout. In short you are stuck with this field for ever!

I wish Stage was not a required field.

Mitesh